# Is omitting a school with blank transcript considered unethical in academia?

Tags: graduate-admissions, ethics

Suppose one was accepted to a school of higher education, but due to personal reasons withdrew three weeks after the beginning of the first semester without registering for and attending courses. Suppose he is now reapplying to other schools and has to submit all transcripts from the universities attended. Is including information about such a school relevant on an application? There is no transcript to submit, and no grades.

Comment: If you did not register (and did not attend), in the U.S. I think we'd say that you never attended (whether or not you were _accepted_).

Answer (score 2):

If you did not enrolled/registered yourself, you did not attend that school of higher education. You could maybe insert this information of being accepted by that school but never registered somewhere in your submissions if there is such space for extra info on the Education section.

Comment: The semester formally started but the plan for study was never submitted and the classes were never attended physically.

Comment: @Jerry But did you had a registration number or something that can prove you enrolled in that school?